# firebase post on webapp

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I've made a simple contact us form using vuejs and firebase realtime database. Since it's just a contact form, I want users to be able to post the data on my app only without signing in. How do I achieve this? When I change the rules for `.write: false` then I get `401 status code unauthorized`.
How do I make it possible to be able to post only on my domain name without signing in? kind of like cors

right now my rules look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `".write": false` you are explicitly telling Firebase to reject all write operations from client-side code. So at that point it giving a 401 result for writes from your web page is the expected behavior.

To allow only writes from your web app, you can consider implementing [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/) with either [reCAPTCHA v3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider) or [reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider).

I'd still recommend implementing Firebase Authentication on top of that, so that you can associate data with a specific user. If you don't want the users to have to sign-in, use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) which signs the user in without them having to enter any credentials.